# Windows 7pro Wireless bridge to Macbook Pro

Tags: windows-7, macos, networking, macbook, macbook-pro

I know this is possible with ubuntu to windows/mac but I am trying to recreate the notion from a windows machine to a mac.

What I need to do is a level of QA / Dev however my main development machine is a windows machine while the issue from what I am told is Mac Safari specific. So rather than go through the pain staking needs to set up my personal mac for my jobs needs and getting it set up with a local enviroment I'd like to just bridge the connection so I can use the local server setup on the windows machine through the mac.

Any idea's? Its all wireless by the way. I also have no control over the router itself though I belive it has a bridge mode set and enabled.

Comment: So, what you're saying is, you're doing web development on a Windows machine, you have an under-development web server/website running on that machine, and you also have a Mac, and you want to use Safari on the Mac to load web pages from the under-development website on your Windows machine? Can you just have your Mac join the same wireless network and point Safari at the IP address of your Windows box that's got the under-development website running on it? I don't understand why your situation requires setting up wireless bridging.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @Spiff that is the generalization of it yes. However the network consists of about 40 machines give or take, all of which are running similar instances of the same server set up for different ends of development. I am working UI/UX in this particular instance. I tried going directly to my Dev boxes ip, and got basically a 404, so I'm trying to figure out how to make it so my parituclar machine can share specifically cross the network with another machine on the network ie: my mac. I had a similar issue when using Ubuntu with a diff company a while back and the solution was a bridge of sorts

Comment: @chris Is your local, under-development website reachable from any other machine on the wireless LAN? If not, then maybe you just need to reconfigure your web server software to listen on your LAN IP address, instead of just the loopback address (127.0.0.1).

Comment: its a wireless network no hardwires anywhere. But no, one comp to the next nothing is accessable through the WLAN. Guess in all Im trying to configure windows so I can do that (or the server which is Tomcat)